# How to report these frequencies in the presence of missing data?

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a `data.frame` with binary factors for medicament treatment, and I want to count medicament use by patient. Rows are patients and columns are medicaments. I want to count how many medicaments (columns) each patient (row) has taken, in the presence of missing data on medicament administration. The objective is to determine how many patients have taken **more than one** med.

Reproducible example:

```
set.seed(1)
M1 <- sample(c("N","Y"), 10, replace = T)
M2 <- sample(c("N","Y"), 10, replace = T)
M3 <- sample(c("N","Y"), 10, replace = T)
M1[5] <- NA; M2[7] <- NA; M3[3] <- NA
meds <- data.frame(M1,M2,M3)
meds$counts.NA <- apply(meds, 1, function(x) { y <- x=="Y"; sum(y)})
meds$counts.noNA <- apply(meds, 1, function(x) { y <- x=="Y"; sum(y, na.rm = T)})
```

My concern is, if I simply ignore the missing data from the counts (column `counts.noNA` they might be perceived as if the patient had **not** taken the meds. OTOH in this example, if I only consider the `counts.NA`, I will loose patient 3, which is known for taken 2 meds.

Which column (`counts.NA` or `counts.noNA`) should I report, and why?

Comment: @gung, although not relevant to the question, my data is on medicament treatment, **not** "mediations". If you revert the edit, I'll be glad to clarify this.

Comment: You have the right to roll back the edit yourself, & certainly have my blessing to do so.

Comment: There, I hope the context is clearer now.

Comment: My apologies for mis-editing your post.

Comment: Do you know anything about why the data might be missing?

Comment: In some cases because of incomplete medical records; other cases records were not accessible.

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of why medical records might be incomplete or inaccessible?

Comment: @gung it would be a case-by-case issue, on a 400+ patients table, so no I don't have this answer. I would assume human error in keeping paper records and system records in sync (or maybe a delay in system input) - my data source is the system records, not the paper records. I estimate about 50-60 of these 400+ patients would be lost if only complete cases were to be considered. I want to communicate the results as faithfully as possible, with minimal information loss.